# Tests of Association When Using Likert-style Ordinal Data

Tags: ordinal-data, contingency-tables, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, fishers-exact-test

I am currently working with some survey data that has ordinal categories for drinking/substance abuse problem (0=Never binge drink, 1=once a month, 2=once a week...4=nearly every day). Right now, my primary focus is trying to test association of having at least one "violent" crime charge (coded as violent=1) vs. having none (coded as violent=0) on these substance abuse distributions. I am not trying to build a through model, just trying to get a feel about the population I'm working with, and find possible leads on variables to look out for.

First method I thought of was Fisher's Exact Test, as most of my other survey questions were binary and it resulted in a nice, clean 2x2 contingency table (e.g. History of mental illness (Y/N) X Violent Crime). But then I realized it's sub-optimal to use Fisher's Exact Test when the variable was ordinal rather than simply categorical.

Deriving the mean score for the likert scale and running a t-test was another idea, but a lot of people seem to be saying I shouldn't do that, as calculating the mean of something like a likert scale can be misleading.

I've tried using Mann-Whitney, but I haven't worked with non parametric methods a lot so I'm shaky on that, and although it seems like the correct test to use, I am no expert and would probably want guidance on that.

Lastly, I am kind of averse to using cumulative ordered logit models since I am nowhere near checking all the assumptions thoroughly and building a model that includes all the relevant variables. I am afraid if I just run something like -ologit violent alcohol-, the resulting p-value could be screwed up as the model is imperfect.

**So what test would you recommend that I use to test for association in a 2x5 contingency table where 2 is categorical/dummy for the violence status and 5 are ordinal categories?**

**Could you correct me if I am making some erroneous assumptions about the tests I am using/thinking of using?**